# What is the difference between Facebook's Share dialog and Feed dialog?

Tags: facebook, sharing

I am trying to figure out which method is better to implement Facebook sharing, but there are surprisingly few resources comparing these two methods directly.

On the Facebook developers' website, they mention that the "Feed dialog" method is deprecated in favor of the Share dialog method. That being said, I notice that many prominent viral content sites (most notably, upworthy.com, perhaps the most Facebook traffic dependent site on the internet) use Feed dialog.

Given that a site like Upworthy uses Feed dialogs, and not Share dialogs, I am wondering if there is some compelling reason to choose them over the more modern share dialogs.

Based on my research, I believe these are the key difference between the two methods:

- Feed dialog does not depend on Open Graph tags, instead it allows you to customize the post image, title, description, etc. via including them in the URL string. This is a huge advantage in my opinion.
- Share Dialog relies on Open Graph tags (which are at the URL / page level), which is a disadvantage in my opinion as you cannot customize the post information as you might want to if you have many images / bits of shareable content on one page.

I am not really sure what "This does not require Facebook Login or any extended permissions, so it is the easiest way to enable sharing on web." means when allowing users to share, and I'm not sure how it differs from the Feed dialog method or if it is really "better".

Can anyone provide more insight into the differences between these methods at a more detailed level than the documentation, and perhaps illustrate why one method would be chosen  over the other?

Comment: Heed the advice about feed dialog being deprecated and use share dialog. You should check out: [feed dialog vs explicit sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521463/feed-dialog-vs-explicit-sharing), [Whats the difference between Facebook Feed Dialog and (Sharer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449634/whats-the-difference-between-facebook-feed-dialog-and-sharer), and [Should I use Facebook Share Dialog or Feed Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332687/should-i-use-facebook-share-dialog-or-feed-dialog-id-need-to-redirect-users-to)

Comment: Is this really a UX question, or could it be migrated to SO? It would probably get closed as duplicate on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technical implementation rather than about UX.